# Measuring Availability Group synchronization lag - Clarifications

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups, filestream

Can I get some help on below

As I have started and learning about the Measuring of Availability Group synchronization lag between replicas inclusive of BCP , I want to understand and learn that does this query or dashboard show the values including FileStream synchronization lag ?

My Databases are with FileStream enabled . 
I am using SQL Server 2014 SP2 AOAG.

Please help me understand the above point and kindly advise me with good link or query to measure the Sync lad between replicas.

Comment: May I know why the question was down marked ? is it formatting or the content I asked ? I want to be aware of for future usage of DBA Stack exchange.

Comment: You may want to update your statements with the query you're talking about or a screenshot of the dashboard to show what you're referencing and what your specific question is about.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the AG Dashboard is made up using the **sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states**  results . Thanks for all help.

I got an answer what I am looking for :

**filestream_send_rate (bigint )**

The rate at which the FILESTREAM files are shipped to the secondary replica, in kilobytes (KB)/second.